# Should init be assigning, or testing equality, on self init?

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I cloned from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git today, and noticed two spots in the code which have this construct:

```
(id) init {
    if ((self == [super init])) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would expect `self` to be assigned here, not tested for equality:

```
(id) init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        ...
    }
}
```

or at the very least:

```
(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is within `src/FBDialog.m` and `sample/Hackbook/Hackbook/DataSet.m`.

(Sorry if this should be in the [bug tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) instead; couldn't find a way to actually *submit* anything there... :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should **assign** self, because `[super init]` may return a different object than self.

Checking for equality will *often* work but isn't required to work. You should always **assign**.

I believe that recent versions of clang even emit warnings when using `==` in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

The template for a new Objective-C class in XCode 3 used to give you #2 (except with fewer parentheses).

Somebody who did not understand that and thought it was a mistake changed it to #1.

I guess Apple decided it was confusing so now in XCode 4 the template gives you #3. In fact it gives a warning for #2 (maybe only without the extra parentheses).

Comment: The warning has been removed in the latest version of clang because this is very common.

Comment: and it was only without extra parentheses that this warning was shown