# Purpose of if(self == [super init])

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have seen `if(self = [super init])`, but I recently came across some code that tests for equality rather than makes an assignment, e.g. `if(self == [super init])`. What is the purpose of this code, and how does it contrast with `if(self = [super init])`?

For context, this is the entire function:

```
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<BSForwardGeocoderDelegate>)aDelegate
{
    if (self == [super init])
    {
        delegate = aDelegate;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956943/why-should-i-call-self-super-init

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840535/should-init-be-assigning-or-testing-equality-on-self-init

Comment: Why the down votes?   Perfectly valid question!

Comment: The questions linked to by Midhun and MarkM seem to disagree. The second answer in Midhun's linked question says that testing for equality is a better than testing assignment, but MarkM's answer says that testing for equality is likely an unintentional syntax mistake.

Comment: @user1 It is because the second answer on Midhun's link -- the part that talks about `==` is flat out wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking for equality makes no sense and is just wrong.

Assigning is because `super` may return a different object.

Comment: Agreed.  The `==` version is simply wrong.  It will work most of the time, but not always.  The `if (self = [super init])` version is slightly ugly (I don't like to see assignments inside if statements), but will produce correct results.